# RRD Performance reporting with GSA/OpenVAS

Tags: openvas

I'm running Greenbone Security Assistant 7.0.2 (on Kali Linux) and the default performance reporting currently goes a "Fallback Report" which only dumps /proc/meminfo to the screen. A note on the page implies that there's more rich reporting but I haven't been able to find anything documented for setting up or enabling it. I'm assuming it's more or less standard RRD reporting. Anyone know how to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the relevant part of the source code [documentation](https://github.com/greenbone/gvm/blob/v7.0.2/INSTALL#L489-L499):

> Prerequisites for generating system reports:
>
> - A program in the PATH, with usage "openvasmr seconds type", where
>   seconds is the number of seconds before now that the report covers,
>   and type is the type of report.  When called with type "titles" the
>   script must print a list of possible types, where the name of the
>   type is everything up to the first space and everything else is a
>   title for the report.  When called with one of these types openvasmr
>   must print a PNG in base64 encoding.  When called with the special
>   type "blank", openvasmr must print a PNG in base64 for the Manager to
>   use when a request for one of the titled types fails.  openvasmr may
>   indicate failure by simply refraining from printing.

Disclaimer: Answer of a NVT Dev @ Greenbone